# Should there be an "undocumented function" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags

I think an "undocumented function" or "undocumented api" could be useful, but I am not sure about the "meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed" requirement listed on the create tag privilege description page.

For example, it could be added to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13512156/cannot-change-windows-timer-resolution-in-c

Comment: What for? And what if a undocumented API becomes documented? I'm not sure I see the use

Comment: Seems like a meta-tag to me. I can't see it being very useful.

Comment: We already have site for such: http://Apple.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not needed and the same as saying you have a question to ask before asking a question.

Just as there are always people smarter than you, there are also people who see you as knowing more.

By the site's definition all questions are about some undocumented or under documented chunk of code or API. Something some user doesn't quite get.

It's as implicit as putting "halp" in the title and a tag for this would be superfluous squatting of a question's definition.